# How can I silence the Yum Python API module output?

Tags: python, yum

Is there a way to prevent the yum API from creating output when it runs?

For instance, if I run this simple code (with yum-3.4.3-132.el7.centos.0.1):

```
import yum
yb = yum.YumBase()
yb.repos.populateSack(mdtype='metadata', cacheonly=0)
```

I get the following output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
```

I don't want to blackhole *all* output, just the output from the yum API.

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on thescouser89's answer here.

I'm not sure if this is an exhaustive list of every Yum logger, but I think it's pretty close. You can disable all of them before you start calling into Yum and it will be completely silent.

```
import logging
from yum.logginglevels import __NO_LOGGING

yumLoggers = ['yum.filelogging.RPMInstallCallback','yum.verbose.Repos', 'yum.verbose.plugin', 
'yum.Depsolve', 'yum.verbose', 'yum.plugin', 'yum.Repos', 'yum', 'yum.verbose.YumBase', 
'yum.filelogging', 'yum.verbose.YumPlugins', 'yum.RepoStorage', 'yum.YumBase', 
'yum.filelogging.YumBase', 'yum.verbose.Depsolve']

for loggerName in yumLoggers:
    logger = logging.getLogger(loggerName)
    logger.setLevel(__NO_LOGGING)
```

You can also override some of the progress bars / event loggers from the various RPM transactions by making a class that inherits [RPMBaseCallback](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/28ad77d00158a45ef145122ef70be3c6c4364ffd/yum/rpmtrans.py#L68) and passing that into the various transaction functions (processTransaction, etc). However, if you're disabling all the loggers as I've done above, those functions will not be called.

Edit: 
Upon further inspection, I think the simplest answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43625141/619255

However, this approach doesn't silence warnings about incomplete transactions, while disabling all of the loggers does.

Answer (score -1):

I looked into the RHEL7 yum code and I believe you can do that in your code like so:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("yum.verbose.YumPlugins")
# Only print critical logs from yum
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

# The "Loaded plugins:" text is printed as a debug. So anything above
# logging.DEBUG should silence it
```