# Silencing Yum API Output

Tags: python, api, yum

I am looking to "silence" the debug level of the yum API in python. For example I am assigning two yum commands to variables like below;

```
import yum
yb = yum.YumBase()

yum_conf = yb.conf.config_file_path
package_list = yb.doPackageLists(pkgnarrow='updates', patterns='', ignore_case=True)
```

When running the script it comes back with the following for CentOS 7:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
* extras: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
* updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
```

And then on CentOS 6:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
```

I don't want this verbose level of printing. I'm thinking this is something to do with the logging level, but am at cross path as to how to alter this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need are these two lines,

```
  yb.preconf.debuglevel = 0
  yb.preconf.errorlevel = 0
```

e.g., a python scipt, `getpkg.py` looks something like the following:

```
  import yum

  yb = yum.YumBase()
  yb.preconf.debuglevel = 0
  yb.preconf.errorlevel = 0
  yb.install(name='emacs-nox')
  yb.resolveDeps()
  yb.processTransaction()
```

Result:

```
~]# python getpkg.py 
Installing: 1:perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch 0/8868 [1/32]
Installing: 1:perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch 144/8868 [1/32]
Installing: 1:perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch 2649/8868 [1/32]
Installing: 1:perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch 5686/8868 [1/32]
....
....
```

Comment: This is perfect, I used just the debug level one which silenced the output. Thanks.

Comment: iamauser - I already have but take note of the following: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect scenario for a context manager. This is either being printed to stdout or stderr, the below technique works for either.

```
import io
import contextlib
import yum

f = io.StringIO()
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):  # or redirect_stderr... or both
    ''' All the output in here is redirected to the filelike object, f '''

    yb = yum.YumBase()
    yum_conf = yb.conf.config_file_path
    package_list = yb.doPackageLists(pkgnarrow='updates', patterns='', 
        ignore_case=True)
s = f.getvalue()  # s now contains all that output you didn't want
```